# Using outer/outside

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

[image]

I want to move the square 1 and 2 into the circle. So which one is the best describing "*moving the squares 1 and 2 into the circle*"?

- *moving outer squares into the circle*
- *moving outside squares into the circle*
- *moving squares outside the circle into the circle*
- *moving squares located outside the circle in to the circle*
- or another suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to: **move squares 1 & 2 into the circle.**

But if you don't wish to number them, it really depends on how specific you want to be:

**Move outer squares into the circle**  would be widely understood (although square 1 is only partially located outside the circle and this might cause confusion).

**Move squares outside the circle into the circle** poses the same problem.

An alternative might be: **Locate all squares within the circle**

However, if you want to refer only to squares 1 & 2, you would need to spell things out: **Move any squares bordering the circle inside the circumference**

If you want them to be neatly arranged, as in your diagram, you would have to be more specific still. But I leave that to some mathematically minded soul